# How can i increment int number in leading zero number?

Tags: python

I am unable to increment a number in leading zero numbers.

```
a = 2
a = ('%02d' % a) #02

a = a + 1
print(a)
```

Code Error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Expected Result:

```
02

03

04

05
```

Can anyone tell me best possible solution.

Comment: Still not using a `for` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time you do:

```
a = a + 1
```

a is of type string. By adding `1` you are combining `string` and `int` types, which is not allowed in this sense.

What you can do is this (while keeping the same structure for clairity)

```
a = 2
b = ('%02d' % a) #02
print(b)

a = a + 1
b = ('%02d' % a) #02
print(b)

#etc.
```

Consider using a `for` loop (as the others mentioned) if you don't want to write all the separate cases.

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing types. By doing `a = a + 1` you're trying to add an `int` to a `string`.

Just divide to 2 variables:

```
a = 2

for i in range(4):
    a_str = ('%02d' % a)
    a = a + 1
    print(a_str)
```

or even save one variable if you simply want to print:

```
a = 2

for i in range(4):
    print('%02d' % a)
    a = a + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is just a printing issue and the leading zero is insignificant, then you can use [print formatting](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/format) like below (the "02" is the width):

```
for a in range(1, 12):
    print(format(a, "02"))

# output
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:

Take an example 'i' and it starts with 0001 and I am incrementing the 'i' but python implicitly removes the zero's
I'm using the for loop to increment the 'i' values

```
length = 4  # number of digits like 0001
for i in range(1,15):
    print('0' * (length - len(str(i))) + str(i))
```

the output will be :

```
0001, 0002, 0003....0010 and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 2
x = ('%02d' % x)
print(str(int(x) + 1).zfill(len(x)))
>> '03'
```

you will have to keep it in a string as once you convert it to int, it strips away the leading 0's as having those will use more space to store the object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a number with a leading zero if the number is lesser than 10, then you can just do this:

```
a = 2
print(('0' if a < 10 else '') + str(a))  # 02
```